# Magento shows attribute if value is null

Tags: php, magento

I have an attribute on my product view and list pages that displays a preview video on a separate page.  I'm pulling in the attribute using my themes product/view.phtml and product/list.phtml.  It has an image button that shows preview now.  The code is have is below.

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getvideo_src()) ?>" TARGET="_blank"><img src="/graphics/preview-now.png" align="absmiddle" style="margin-top: 10px;" alt="Preview Now"></a>
```

The problem is that I don't want this image to display if the product attribute is null or blank.  I tried the code below in a few variations but that wouldn't work.

```
< ?php if($_product->getvideo_src() != '') { ?>
      <span><a href="<?php echo $_product->getvideo_src(); ?>" target="_blank"><img src="/graphics/preview-now.png" align="absmiddle" style="margin-top: 10px;" alt="Preview Now"></a></span>
< ?php  } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `isset`.  Also your magic get formatting is off.  You had `getvideo_src()` when it should be camel-cased like `getVideoSrc()`.

```
<?php if(isset($_product->getVideoSrc())) { ?>
  <span><a href="<?php echo $_product->getVideoSrc(); ?>" target="_blank"><img src="/graphics/preview-now.png" align="absmiddle" style="margin-top: 10px;" alt="Preview Now"></a></span>
<?php  } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 <?php if($_product->getVideoSrc()) : ?>
      ...
 <?php endif; ?>
```

or

```
 <?php if($_product->getData('video_src')) : ?>
      ...
 <?php endif; ?>
```